# What should I do when a user with poor grammar and formatting denies my edit?

Tags: support

As the title suggests, recently a user denied my edits and insisted on sort of copying them and making my edits their own...

#### What to do?

What should I do when this happens, as I believe it has happened in the past and not just today???

You can find the specific case I'm talking about, [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015643/new-to-installing-ubuntu).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As already explained, no they didn't!

In the future, if you want to find out why any edits are rejected, there is a section in your profile under *Activity* → *all actions* → *suggestions*.

In this case:

> suggested [rejected edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/816830) on New to installing Ubuntu

Click on *rejected edit*, not the title:

> Rejected 12 hours ago:
> Community♦ reviewed this 12 hours ago: **Reject**
> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

It was auto-rejected by the system user *Community♦*, because a different edit was submitted at the same time by another user. Bad luck!

Answer (score 8):

Your edit wasn't rejected intentionally; the system rejected it automatically when an edit was posted by the author, who was probably already editing when you submitted yours.

There is no good way to predict this sort of conflict, and as such they don't count against you in any way.